# How to open html document within <div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

I have been attempting to build a personal site for myself and I have the skeleton built. I have navigation buttons to the left of my page and a content area that has a class of `.main`. I would like to make so that when a button is clicked the content loads within the `.main` div. I have no idea how to go about this so any input towards a solution would be appreaciated. Below is the html and css code I have so far.

CSS:

```css
  html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
html{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
body{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url(../images/background-lights1.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Asar', serif;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:75px;
}
aside{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 550px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FEB41C;
  
}

#buttons li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;    
    background-color: #000000;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 38px 0 38px 0;
    width: 150px;
    border-top: 1px solid #3E474F;

    
}
#buttons li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 3px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;

}
#buttons li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FEB41C;
    
}

#myPicture{
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #FEB41C;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;

}
.main{
    background: linear-gradient(#849696, #FEFFFB);
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #FEB41C;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FEB41C;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/limit-dne.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asar' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <title>The Limit Does Not Exist</title>
    <header>
     <img src="images/Dion.jpg" id="myPicture" alt="A picture of the site creator">
    </header>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="main">
     <aside>
    <ul id="buttons">
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
     </ul>
   </aside> 
  </div>    
    <script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

Comment: make ajax call to your clicked pages and load the content in the main div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript: You can do this with some simple jQuery. For Example:

```
var i = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home').click(function(){
         if (i == false) {
              $('#home_content').css("display","block");
              i = true;
         } else {
              $('#home_content').css("display","none");
              i = false;
         };
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<aside>
<ul id="buttons">
<li id="home"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<div id="home_content" style="display: none"></div>
<li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</aside> 
</div>
```

Comment: If you are trying to display a HTML page within, your main div. You can use an iframe tag within the content div.